# Why lists:filter doesn't work well?

Tags: erlang

Using postgresql's sql, from the other documents, It is known that several special keywords should be filtered for preventing sql inject attack, such as ', ;, &, <, >.

```
quote(Value) when is_integer(Value)->
    Value;
quote(Value) ->
    %% seperate_by(["'",Value,"'"],"").
    Value_a = lists:dropwhile(fun($')->true;
                 ($;)->true;
                 ($<)->true;
                 ($>)->true;
                 ($&)->true;
                     (_)->false
                      end,Value),
    seperate_by(["'",Value_a,"'"],"").

(emacs@yus-iMac.local)62> john_worker:quote("<>&asdf'").
"'asdf''"
(emacs@yus-iMac.local)63> john_worker:quote("'asdf").
"'asdf''"
(emacs@yus-iMac.local)64> john_worker:quote("'asdf").
"'asdf'"
(emacs@yus-iMac.local)65> john_worker:quote("'asdf").
"'asdf'"
(emacs@yus-iMac.local)66> john_worker:quote("a'sdf").
"'a'sdf'"
(emacs@yus-iMac.local)67> john_worker:quote("a>sdf").
"'a>sdf'"
```

The lists:filter works well for words prefixing by these special characters, but not works for other condition. Why?

Comment: `lists:dropwhile` will drop the head until the predicate returns false -- this is consistent with your results. I think `lists:filter` is what you want, but then you'll have to invert your current predicate's boolean return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure of what you are expecting as result, if you simply want to skip those special characters, you can use a list comprehension:

```
quote(Value) ->
     "'" ++ [X || X <- Value , X =/= $', X =/= $;, X =/= $<, X =/= $>, X =/= $&] ++ "'".
```